# I am trying to implement dijkstra's algorithm for a class

Tags: c, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am supposed to get `0-3-6-5` as the output for the cost. `-1-0-3-1` for the output of the previous array. and `1-1-1-1` for the visit array.

I am getting `0-3-7-5` for my output in the cost and `-1-0-1-1` for the previous. Please help if you can.

I have tried to see where the 7 comes from when it should be a six and I am not figuring it out. This is the first time I have coded in C language so it might seem kind of sloppy.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define infinity 999

int main (void){

    int dij[4][4] = {{0,3,8,6},
        {3,0,4,2},
        {8,4,0,1},
        {6,2,1,0}};

    int visit[4];
    int cost[4];
    int previous[4];

    //filling the visit, cost, previous arrays
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        visit[j] = 0;
        cost[j] = infinity;
        previous[j] = -1;
    }//adding the values to the arrays    
    //node I am on
    cost[0] = 0; //first position in the cost array is set to 0
    int counter = 0; //counter for the while loop    
    int currentRow = 0; //checks for the rows holding th smallest value in the dij array
        while(counter < 4){
                int min = infinity; //min value is set to infinity at the beginning of program            
                for(int y=0; y<4; y++){                   
                    //if the cost at the current position in th cost array is < min and the node is not visited
                    if(cost[y] < min && visit[y] == 0){
                        min = cost[y];
                        currentRow = y;
                    }//if                    
                    visit[currentRow] = 1;
                }//for loop for col of dij array.
                //loop to look at the cost array to find the lowest cost unvisited node and set row to that index value
                for(int x=0; x<4; x++){                    
                    if(visit[x] != 1){             
                        if(min + dij[currentRow][x] < cost[x]){
                            cost[x] = min + dij[currentRow][x];
                            previous[x] = currentRow;
                        }
                    }
                }
                counter++;
        }//while loop for x column of dij array.
```

Comment: Try walking through every possible step by hand and having your code print all the steps and see where it diverges. I don't know if anybody is going to debug your logic error for you.

Comment: I have found exactly where it changes to 7 but then just goes on its merry way. When counter = 1, currentRow = 1, min = 3, x = 1 is when it gets changed to 7. For some reason it is not going on in that row or column and grabbing that 2 in index 3. I am at the point of this program where I am contemplating life and possibly dropping the major or taking the F. It is pretty frustrating.

Comment: Whenever the code gets to index dij[1][3] or dij[3][1] it is not taking that 2 instead of the 4 that it takes prior to get the 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visit flag must be outside of the for statements. Because the visit flag must be on iteration time.

```
for(int y=0; y<4; y++){                   

    if(cost[y] <= min && visit[y] == 0){
        min = cost[y];
        currentRow = y;
    }//if                    
    //<-- not here
}//for loop for col of dij array.

visit[currentRow] = 1;
```

Here is full source code with print values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define infinity 999

int main (void)
{

    int dij[4][4] = {
        {0,3,8,6},
        {3,0,4,2},
        {8,4,0,1},
        {6,2,1,0}
    };

    int visit[4];
    int cost[4];
    int previous[4];

    //filling the visit, cost, previous arrays
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        visit[j] = 0;
        cost[j] = infinity;
        previous[j] = -1;
    }//adding the values to the arrays    

    //node I am on
    cost[0] = 0; //first position in the cost array is set to 0
    int counter = 0; //counter for the while loop    
    int currentRow = 0; //checks for the rows holding th smallest value in the dij array

    while(counter < 4)  
    {
        int min = infinity; //min value is set to infinity at the beginning of program            
        for(int y=0; y<4; y++){                   
            //if the cost at the current position in th cost array is < min and the node is not visited
            if(cost[y] <= min && visit[y] == 0){
                min = cost[y];
                currentRow = y;
            }//if                    

        }//for loop for col of dij array.

        visit[currentRow] = 1;

        //loop to look at the cost array to find the lowest cost unvisited node and set row to that index value
        for(int x=0; x<4; x++){ 

            if(visit[x] != 1 && cost[currentRow] + dij[currentRow][x] < cost[x] && cost[currentRow] != infinity )
            {             
                //if(min + dij[currentRow][x] < cost[x])
                {
                    cost[x] = cost[currentRow] + dij[currentRow][x];
                    previous[x] = currentRow;
                }
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }//while loop for x column of dij array.


    printf("visit   cost    previous  \n");

    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n", visit[j], cost[j], previous[j]);
    }//adding the values to the arrays  

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be as follows,

```
visit   cost    previous
1        0       -1
1        3       0
1        6       3
1        5       1
```

Have a nice day~~

Comment: Thank you so much! I had stared at that for 4 hours and it was really just one line of code that needed to be moved. This stuff is crazy. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Jeremy you are welcome, if so, choose my answer and close your question plz~~^^